# get relation then get from a table - php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

I have 3 table for example : post , attach , relation.

and when I select post, after than I need get attached file to this post.

Now I have to select from relation table. because attach can add to an other posts.

I select the post easily, then now what is the best way to select attaches?

the `post` table:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | post_title   | post_text   |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | test title 1 | test text 1 |
|  2 | test title 2 | test text 2 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

the `attach` table:

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | url                           |
+----+-------------------------------+
|  1 | http://xxxxxx.ir/img/logo.png |
|  2 | http://xxxxxx.ir/img/tut.png  |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

the `relation` table:

```
+-----+-----+
| src | dst |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
+-----+-----+
```

and my tried sql code:

```
SELECT dst FROM relation where src = 1 ;
```

and after than I implode in php :

```
$ids = implode( $result );
```

then my final query:

```
SELECT * FROM attach WHERE id IN( $ids ) ;
```

I need better way and SQL.

Comment: Is there a reason the relation isn't stored in the `attach` table directly? Can a row from `attach` be related to multiple `post` rows?

Comment: Yes you think replace tag with attach one tag or attach can be added to many post not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JOIN to bring in the data from the attach table.

```
SELECT r.src, a.* FROM relation AS r JOIN attach AS a ON r.src=a.id WHERE r.src = 1;
```

Comment: Prefect Bro, can you give an reference for Join tutorial?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/
and
http://www.halfgaar.net/sql-joins-are-easy are good resources